# Mapbox Layer line style & animation

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to make a simple line between two points on the map with a little bit of custom styling.

[image]

This is what I got so far, now I need:

1. Is it possible to make these dashed lines to be circle right now is small lines?

```
map.addLayer({
    id: 'route',
    source: 'route',
    type: 'line',
    layout: {
        'line-cap': 'round',
        'line-join': 'round',
    },
    paint: {
        'line-width': 4,
        'line-color': '#0c5ce5',
        'line-dasharray': [0, 3],
    },
})
```

2. I need a simple animation that will animate a line to move from right to left (server too client), something like a slider or not sure how to describe animation but look at this like signal coming from the server to client. I actually find something that works for me but having a problem when I put `'line-cap': 'round'` and also not quite sure how to create `dashArraySeq` for my `line-dasharray` too look like circles?

   ```
   var animationStep = 50
   var step = 0

   let dashArraySeq = [
       [0, 4, 3],
       [1, 4, 2],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 3],
       [0, 2, 3, 2],
       [0, 3, 3, 1],
   ]

   setInterval(() => {
       step = (step + 1) % dashArraySeq.length
       map.setPaintProperty(layerId, 'line-dasharray', dashArraySeq[step])
   }, animationStep)
   ```

Comment: Check this http://edge-demo-8cea2d.akri.io/ , same animation but with circles instead of dashed lines.